# SwiftUI: add SwiftUI Path to Scenekit Scene

Tags: scenekit, swiftui

I'm trying to add add SwiftUI Path to a Scenekit Scene (as SCNShape).

I created:
Scenekit View (image 1)
SwiftUI Path (image 2)

Then I tried to call the SwiftUI Path, based on the approach bellow:
[Unable to create circle using UIBezierPath and SCNShape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730486/unable-to-create-circle-using-uibezierpath-and-scnshape)

```
   let scnpath = ContentView()
   let shape = SCNShape(path: scnpath)
   let shapeNode = SCNNode(geometry: shape)
```

Didn't work, as results bellow:

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ScenekitView : UIViewRepresentable {
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!


    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // add SwiftUI Path to Scenekit Scene

        let scnpath = ContentView()
        let shape = SCNShape(path: scnpath)
        let shapeNode = SCNNode(geometry: shape)

        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)


        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = SCNView()
        return scnView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ scnView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        scnView.scene = scene


    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ScenekitView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScenekitView()
        .colorScheme(.dark)
        .previewDevice("iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)")
    }
}
#endif
```

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

                Path { path in
                   path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 63.5, y: 98.38))
                           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 920.14, y: 0))
                           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 1094.24, y: 584.81))
                           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 920.14, y: 938.58))
                           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 498.47, y: 1279.73))
                           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 211.79, y: 938.58))
                           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 617.65, y: 584.81))
                           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 735.35, y: 295.94))
                           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 332.02, y: 349.08))
                           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 672.25))
                           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 63.5, y: 98.38))
                }
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 3)
            }
        }

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Really appreciate any help!

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Your SwiftUI `ContentView` is a `View`, which is struct, but `SCNShape` expected `UIBezierPath` which is a class. So if you want to join those different concepts, you have to do something like the following:

In `ContentView`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let path =  Path { path in
       path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 63.5, y: 98.38))
               path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 920.14, y: 0))
               path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 1094.24, y: 584.81))
               path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 920.14, y: 938.58))
               path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 498.47, y: 1279.73))
               path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 211.79, y: 938.58))
               path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 617.65, y: 584.81))
               path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 735.35, y: 295.94))
               path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 332.02, y: 349.08))
               path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 672.25))
               path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 63.5, y: 98.38))
    }

    var body: some View {
        self.path
            .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 3)
    }
}
```

In `ScenekitView`

```
let scnpath = ContentView().path.cgPath
let shape = SCNShape(path: UIBezierPath(cgPath: scnpath), extrusionDepth: 1.0)
```

Comment: thanks a ton Asperi!

now it builds, so almost there! : )

But still I don't see the SwiftUI Path on the SceneKit scene...
I tried adding some materials, but didn't work. 

Did you get the SwiftUI Path on your SceneKit scene?

Comment: I just confirmed that SwiftUI Path is not on Scenekit Scene (so its not a matter of attaching material), as I exported a the .scn file from view debugger and only ship is there...

Comment: complementary:

found this:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-uibezierpath-and-cgpath-in-swiftui

But also didn't work...

"If you’re starting with a CGPath rather than a UIBezierPath, things are even easier. This line:

let path = Path(bezierPath.cgPath)
Becomes this:

let path = Path(yourCGPath)"

Answer (score 0):

[image]try this:

1) you did not add your shapenode to the scene - so you won't see it

2) in the beginning, if you are not so well experienced with scenekit, you should not control the camera yourself...let this scenekit do for you, so i deleted your camera (because it needs the right position + angle so that you can really see something

3.) update the shape to your shape like asperi told you - this is one way you can go (i did not put this in my running example, because it would be too easy for you ;))

4.) result is as it is shown in picture

5.) i don't know whether you know: in the simulator you can only see scenekitviews if you tap the "play" button in the simulator...

```
struct ScenekitView : UIViewRepresentable {

    let scene = SCNScene()


    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {

        let uiView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
  //      scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // add SwiftUI Path to Scenekit Scene

        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))

        let shape = SCNShape(path: bezierPath, extrusionDepth: 50)
        let shapeNode = SCNNode(geometry: shape)

        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 25)

     //   scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(shapeNode)

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = SCNView()
        scnView.scene = scene
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        scnView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)

        return scnView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ scnView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        print("test")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make it a bittle bit "sexier" you can add specular and a light...and you get:

[image]

code here:

```
struct ScenekitView : UIViewRepresentable {

    let scene = SCNScene()


    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {

        let uiView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()

        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))

        let shape = SCNShape(path: bezierPath, extrusionDepth: 40)
        let shapeNode = SCNNode(geometry: shape)

        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        material.specular.contents = UIColor.white

        let light = SCNLight()
        light.type = .spot
        cameraNode.light = light

        shape.materials = [material]

        shapeNode.rotation = SCNVector4(0.2, 0.3, 0.1, CGFloat.pi / 2)

        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 5, y: 16, z: 85)

        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(shapeNode)

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = SCNView()
        scnView.scene = scene
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        scnView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400)

        return scnView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ scnView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        print("test")

    }
}
```